# Formal synonym for "sick of [food]"?

Tags: synonyms

For example, if someone's boss caters Chipotle every week, is there a word or phrase to substitute for "sick of" that's more polite and formal when confronting the boss?

Comment: I would say that I am weary of eating the same cuisine every week and that I am craving something different: just for a change. The implication here is that it's temporary, which should be less confrontational.
The word "weary" is hopefully viewed as more polite than the phrase "sick of". This would be the case in Britain, in my experience. Use of the phrase "tired of" could easily be considered a complaint.

Comment: [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126802/english-word-equivalent-of-%E8%86%A9-sick-of-something-due-to-overindulgence) has some relevant answers. [Satiated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/satiate) can have this meaning, but I wouldn't use it in the context of confronting my boss, when some more tact and politeness would be required, as in DjinTonic's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can say (from [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fed+up+with+something))

> We are **fed up with** chipotle.

which is literally true too. Of course, you can soften the impact by adding something like

> It's great food, but we'd love to be more adventurous / try other tastes / etc.

Comment: This is just as informal as what it's supposed to be replacing though

Comment: It's maybe less informal than "sick of", but it's certainly not very formal. If you can imagine a small child saying something in a whiny voice, it's probably not formal.

Comment: This becoming a matter of opinion, I have posted an equivalent saying that isn't quite as abrupt. OP talks about 'confronting' the boss, so what exactly does 'polite' mean here?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be polite/tactful because it's the boss, you could just suggest another place or two and let your boss "get the message". If you do want to give the reason, perhaps:

> **Could we vary our lunch menu next time and order from A or B instead of Chipotle?**

If you do want to refer to the the monotony, perhaps:

> **We've all gotten a bit tired of Chipotle for lunch. Could we try A or B for a
> change?**

Answer (score 0):

You might say that you’ve **had enough of** Chipotle, or that your team has **had our fill of** their food.  A polite, casual way to say it might be, “I’m Chipotle’d out.”  In your situation, I would probably ask the boss, even more politely, “Do you think we could get something else for a change?”  This is phrased as a positive suggestion and doesn’t rule out having Chipotle ever again in the future.

If you literally mean that something makes you feel ill, the word for that is **nauseated**.